# Pass environment variables to nested children

Tags: linux, bash, shell, environment-variables, sh

I have some environment variables that are being set, and am trying to access them via a child process of a child process. I am trying to use shell to start another process. In my example it is just another shell script to keep things simple.

I went through the shell documentation, and tried using the `-a` flag and that did not work. It will work if i explicitly copy over the env variables from the parent to the child.

a.sh

```sh
#!/bin/sh
# does not work here

 echo $FOO
```

parent.sh

```sh
#!/bin/sh
export FOO=bar
sudo -H -u username nohup sh -c "echo $FOO #works here; sh ./a.sh"
```

It will however work if i explicitly pass in FOO to the inline shell script

```sh
#!/bin/sh

export FOO=bar
sudo -H -u username nohup sh -c "echo $FOO;export FOO=$FOO; sh ./a.sh"
```

Is there a more elegant solution to passing env variables to nested children?

In my actual implementation code, it is not a shell script I am trying to use, but starting another process that depends on the env variables, so sourcing a script would not be viable.

Comment: Neat question. It was my understanding that as long as it is run from a process for the same user the environment is inherited.

Comment: So a couple of things could be going on. Depending on your system "sh" could mean an actual /bin/sh or a symlink to bash. Also, the shebang on a.sh could be pointing to a different shell than the parent shell. IIRC, exporting a variable has virtually no limit as to how many children will see it so it seems likely that the issue has something to do with those rather than the variable not being available to the children shell

Comment: I just updated the example to include the shebangs.

Comment: The problem here is specific to `sudo`, which does not pass inherited environment variables to the process it runs for security reasons. (It does if you use the `-E` option, but only if `sudo` is configured to allow that for a given user or command.)

Answer (score 2):

Because sudo does not preserve environment by default when starting new process, you should instruct it to keep a certain var explicitly:

```
sudo FOO=100 -H -u username nohup sh -c "sh ./a.sh"
nohup: ignoring input and appending output to ‘nohup.out’
cat nohup.out
100
```

Answer (score 1):

`sudo` does not preserve the caller's environment unless you use the `-E` option, and even then `sudo` must be configured to *allow* the environment to be preserved for a given user or command.

Your first example, `sudo -H -u username nohup sh -c "echo $FOO #works here; sh ./a.sh"`, is equivalent (after shell processing) to

```
sudo -H -u username nohup sh -c "echo bar; sh ./a.sh"
```

but the `sh` process started by `sudo` won't have `FOO` in its environment.
(`sudo -H -u username -E nohup sh -c "sh ./a.sh"` *might* work, though, depending on the local security policy. `-E` is a *request*, not a command.)

Your second example, after shell processing, is

```
sudo -H -u username nohup sh -c "echo bar;export FOO=bar; sh ./a.sh"
```

Here, `sh` isn't inheriting `FOO` from the shell that calls `sudo`; instead, you are running a shell process that *itself* defines a *new* variable `FOO` in *its* environment, which `a.sh` then inherits.

Comment: -E should work, but normally you don't want to pass ALL the environment to your child process ( e.g. passing PATH/HOME env vars  might  cause troubles ) , so VAR=value is more accurate approach

Comment: Good point, though those are still subject to local security policy, and may not be permitted.

Comment: Does it apply to VAR=value approach as well?

Comment: "Variables passed on the command
       line are subject to restrictions imposed by the security policy plugin." However, I think the policy can permit explicitly listed variables while rejecting inherited variables as a whole.

Comment: IMO, any workarounds are beyond the scope of the question, as they require cooperation from the system administrator to provide the necessary configuration in the `sudoers` file.